# JPA query not producing same results for equivalent MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am working in a SpringBoot JPA backend project with MySQL dialect. In my database there are `Conference` records of [id, creator_identifier, date], which in the JPA entity the `date` is modelled as a `LocalDateTime`. I have the following records in the database.

[1, “test@example.com” ,2020-11-10 00:00:00]

[2, “test@example.com” ,2020-11-10 10:00:00]

[3,  “test@example.com” , 2020-11-24 10:00:00]

When I do the following query in a MySQL console,

```
SELECT c.id, c.creator_identifier, c.date FROM Conference c WHERE c.date > '2020-11-10 03:00:00' AND c.creator_identifier = 'test@example.com' ORDER BY c.date
```

I will get

[2,test@example.com,2020-11-10 10:00:00]

[3,test@example.com,2020-11-24 10:00:00]

Which is my expected output.

However when I do what I think would be the equivalent in a JPA query in a `Repository` class where the parameters are passed in by a `Logic` class, and I run this at a system time of 11am.

**method in ConferenceLogic.java**

```
public List<Conference> findByRecentDate(UserI userInfo) {
    LocalDateTime adjustedTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(8);
    List<Conference> queryResult =  conferenceRepository.findByRecentDate(userInfo.getUserEmail(), adjustedTime);
    //Some other logic
}
```

**method in ConferenceRepository.java**

```
public interface ConferenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Conference, Long> {



    @Query("SELECT c.id, c.creatorIdentifier, c.date FROM Conference c WHERE c.date > ?2 AND c.creatorIdentifier = ?1 ORDER BY c.date")
    List<Conference> findByRecentDate(String email, LocalDateTime adjustedTime);
}
```

I will get the following results

[1, “test@example.com” ,2020-11-10 00:00:00]

[2, “test@example.com” ,2020-11-10 10:00:00]

[3,  “test@example.com” , 2020-11-24 10:00:00]

Which is not what I expected. I minus 8 hours as the data stored in the database seems to store in UTC time, which rolls back 8h behind my application logic, which makes it equivalent to the mySQL query. Does anyone know what is the problem here and how to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try instantiating a Calendar, in this case I think you could abstract from the time zone, to pass a specific date, something like this:

```
//Initialice with current date
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

//Substract hours
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -hoursToSubtract);
//To get Date object use c.getTime();
```

And in your repository method:

```
public interface ConferenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Conference, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c.id, c.creatorIdentifier, c.date FROM Conference c WHERE c.date > ?2 AND c.creatorIdentifier = ?1 ORDER BY c.date")
    List<Conference> findByRecentDate(String email, Date adjustedTime);
}
```